# Is a local multisite installation equivalent to multiple VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache, local-installation

Will a [local multisite installation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18174/one-wordpress-install-serving-multiple-virtual-hosts) achieve the same thing as setting up multiple separate VirtualHosts in httpd-vhosts.conf, even if the sites will not be multisite in the production environment?

Comment: Last question: are these two questions more appropriate for stack overflow?

Comment: Yes to your last question.

Comment: Ok then another question. What's the tag "local-installation" here for?

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the original question, so this answer is to my original, more specific question about Apache setup.

Do Apache variable DOCUMENT_ROOT and PHP variable doc_root need to match exactly?

In my local development setup under MAMP for Windows, in file httpd.conf I set DocumentRoot as

```
DocumentRoot "C:/MAMP/htdocs"
```

whereas in httpd-vhosts.conf I set

```
DocumentRoot "C:/MAMP/htdocs/my-dev-install"
```

This seems to work ok with one site, but how do I get multiple sites working on localhost without having to switch on and off each Virtual Host to pivot between sites?

I'll update this answer as I find pieces.

First, `DocumentRoot` definitions in httpd-vhosts.conf will override the default defined in httpd.conf,

> which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a  definition.  These values also provide defaults for any  containers you may define later in the file.

--(comment from httpd.conf)

My `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1     example.d1
::1             example.d1
127.0.0.1     example.d2
::1             example.d2
```

My `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# ======= New  - theme 1 =======
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/MAMP/htdocs/my-dev-install-1"
    ServerName example.d1
    ServerAlias example.d1
    # these 4 lines enable error logs       ====modify the log names to make it clear which dev site the errors belong to
    RewriteLogLevel 3
    RewriteLog "C:/MAMP/logs/rewrite.log"
    ErrorLog "C:/MAMP/logs/d1-error_log" 
    CustomLog "C:/MAMP/logs/d1-access_log" common 
 </VirtualHost>
 
# ======= New  - theme 2 =======
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/MAMP/htdocs/another-dev-install-2"
    ServerName example.d2
    ServerAlias example.d2
    # these 4 lines enable error logs
    RewriteLogLevel 3
    RewriteLog "C:/MAMP/logs/rewrite.log"
    ErrorLog "C:/MAMP/logs/d2-error_log" 
    CustomLog "C:/MAMP/logs/d2-access_log" common 
 </VirtualHost>
```

The `.htaccess` files have only standard WordPress language (no difference between the two).

Partial success -- when I visit `http://example.d1` or `http://example.d2` , Apache sends me to the correct sites' home pages. However, clicking on links within .d2 take me back to `localhost`, which somehow is defined as the first site (`example.d1`).

Could be a 302 in my browser perhaps. Or, maybe I need to play with the `NameVirtualHost *` statement.